# Get Jenkins build parameter inside java code

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have a question about build parameters in Jenkins.

I want add build parameter (url) on Jenkins, and write there any URL, and then use it in code.

Is it posible, and if it is, how I can do this?

`System.getenv("PARAM_NAME");` isn't working for me.

Thanks a lot =)

Comment: could you get an answer to this question? I have similar scenario and looking for an apt solution for it. I was also trying System.getenv but does not seem to work. In y case, my jenkins job is parameterized and I try to get that parameter value in java code in my android app

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing java code or jenkins plugin for instance, you can simply do this:

```
import hudson.model.AbstractProject;
AbstractProject job.getLastBuild().getBuildVariables().containsKey("PARAM_NAME")
```

Comment: Since the OP wants to fetch the value, I would think `get("PARAM_NAME")` is a better suggestion than `containsKey("PARAM_NAME")`, which in this case only determines whether a build-parameter named "PARAM_NAME" exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could have jenkins modify your values.xml file before compiling.  That would be the easiest way I can quickly think of.

Comment: can you provide me with some example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [EnvInject+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

Some use cases

- To remove inherited environment variables (PATH, ANT_HOME, ...) at node level (master/slave), available by default for a job run.
- To inject variables in the first step of the job (before the SCM checkout)
- To inject variables based on user parameter values
- To execute an initialization script before a SCM checkout.
- To execute an initialization script after a SCM checkout
- To inject variables as a build step obtained from a file filled in by a previous build step
- **To know environment variables used for a build**

Comment: Yes, it looks like I looking for, but I can't find any useful article how i can get values(of environment variables) in java code.

Comment: You can use `System.getenv("PARAM_NAME");` if you used the plugin to inject the variable into the environment. Or maybe `System.getProperty("PARAM_NAME")`

Comment: 1. I've enable " 
Inject environment variables to the build process" section. 2. Then I've add "TEST_STRING=hello world" in "Properties Content". 3. In MainActivity class I've add "System.getenv("TEST_STRING")". And when I build application, I see that value returned by System.getenv("TEST_STRING") is "null". what I did wrong?

Comment: @IvanB... could you get an answer to this question? I have similar scenario and looking for an apt solution for it. I was also trying System.getenv but does not seem to work. In y case, my jenkins job is parameterized and I try to get that parameter value in java code in my android app